# Rate of Koetter-Kschischang Codes

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I'm studying this [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0703061.pdf) on coding theory. Here $W$ denotes a $N$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. A code $C$ then consists of code words $V\in C$, where $V\subseteq W$ is a subspace of $W$. Let $l$ denote the maximum dimension of a codeword $V$, i.e. $l=\max_{V\in C} \dim (V)$. Now the article defines the rate of this code as
$$ R=\frac{\log_q|C|}{Nl}$$
but I'm not sure why this is a natural definition. Clearly transmitting a codeword requires transmitting $N\cdot l$ symbols in $\mathbb{F}_q$. But shouldn't this be done for every codeword? And I guess $|C|$ can be thought of as the total number of information symbols, so why do we take $q$-logarithm?

Comment: $|C|$ is the total number of codewords. If you want to transmit $k$ $q$-ary symbols worth of information, you need to have $q^k$ choices for a codeword. If $|C|=q^k$, then $k=\log_q|C|$. Other than that I'm not at all up to speed with what goes on in network coding. A key differences here is that codewords are subspaces, and the ambient playground is the Grassmannian. This is in sharp contrast to usual error-correcting codes, where the code itself is a subspace, words are individual vectors, and the ambient playground is a bigger vector space together with its Hamming metric.